# Joining nodes of graph

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to draw a graph  similar to

[image]

in latex but I want edges to touch vertices.

My attempt:

```
\node (f) at (0,0) {$F$};
\node (g) at (1,0) {$G$};
\node (e) at (2,0) {$E$};
\node (d) at (2,1) {$D$};
\node (a) at (2,2) {$A$};
\node (b) at (3,2) {$B$};
\draw[black, thick] (a)--(b);
\draw[black, thick] (c)--(b);
\draw[black, thick] (d)--(c);
\draw[black, thick] (d)--(e);
```

but edges still don't touch vertices. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The code

```
\node (a) at (10,0) {$\circ$};
\node (b) at (11,-1) {$\circ$};
\node (c) at (11,-2) {$\circ$};
\node (d) at (12,-3) {$\circ$};
\node (e) at (11,-4) {$\circ$};


\draw[black, thick] (a.center)--(b.center)--(c.center)--(d.center)--(e.center);
```

produces this graph [image]

It would be nice if I were able to fill nodes with black color. If I put the code

```
\node [fill=black](a) at (10,0) {$\circ$};
\node [fill=black](b) at (11,-1) {$\circ$};
\node (c) at (11,-2) {$\circ$};
\node (d) at (12,-3) {$\circ$};
\node (e) at (11,-4) {$\circ$};


\draw[black, thick] (a.center)--(b.center)--(c.center)--(d.center)--(e.center);
```

It produces this graph [image]

However I want nodes to be circular and small and edges drawn from node border to node border.

Comment: `outer sep=0pt` would work (also play with `nodes={draw}`), but your code snippet uses non-empty node text, which is not the same in your image, is it?

Comment: Does my answer doesn't solve your problem? See addendum to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your code fragment has error (undefined node `c`)
- Arrows touch nodes border. To see this, in MWE below nodes' borders are drawn at first two nodes
- It is not entirely clear, what you after. Please always provide a MWE not just code fragment

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone} % ;-)
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {circle, inner sep=2pt}]
\node[draw] (f) at (0,0) {$F$};
\node[draw] (g) at (1,0) {$G$};
\node[fill=cyan] (e) at (2,0) {$E$};
\node (d) at (2,1) {$D$};
\node (a) at (2,2) {$A$};
\node (b) at (3,2) {$B$};
\draw[black, thick] (a)--(b) -- (d) --(e) --(g) -- (f);    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Tiny whit space between node `E` and arrows  are equal to `outer sep` distance which make space for (half of width) node's border. Hence it is absent at this node, it show up. If you set this distance to zero, for example by

```
every node/.style = {circle, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt}
```

then they will disappear:

[image]

**Addendum**
Already from above examples follows how you can solve your problem You need to define style of your nodes (as is done in examples). Because your question is still not entirely clear what is your problem, I defined nodes style so, that you can observe differences if you at nodes use border lines or not and if you just fill them.

Now I guess that you like to have the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone} % ;-)
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, circle, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
circle, inner sep=2pt}]
\node (f) at (0,0) {};
\node (g) at (1,0) {};
\node (e) at (2,0) {};
\node (d) at (2,1) {};
\node (a) at (2,2) {};
\node (b) at (3,2) {};
\draw[black, thick] (a)--(b) -- (d) --(e) --(g) -- (f);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please observe, that node styles is defined in the option of `tikzpicture` as

```
every node/.style = {draw, circle, inner sep=2pt}
```

The `every node` is instruction that this style had to be applied to all nodes in picture. If you have some other nodes in pictures, for example labels to nodes or arrows, which should have different style, then is better to give a name to nodes' style, for example `V` (as shortness for Vertices) and write above MWE as:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone} % ;-)
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
V/.style = {draw, circle, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\node[V] (f) at (0,0) {};
\node[V] (g) at (1,0) {};
\node[V] (e) at (2,0) {};
\node[V] (d) at (2,1) {};
\node[V] (a) at (2,2) {};
\node[V] (b) at (3,2) {};
\draw[black, thick] (a)--(b) -- (d) --(e) --(g) -- (f);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem like yours in the past.
Just try adding center to your points like:

```
\draw[black, thick] (a.center)--(b.center);
\draw[black, thick] (c.center)--(b.center);
\draw[black, thick] (d.center)--(c.center);
\draw[black, thick] (d.center)--(e.center);
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer to OP's issue, since it doesn't draw from node borders but from their centers.